# Управление командными элементами управления (MenuItem) в зависимости от состояния контента (UserViews)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня в программе имеется несколько разных UserView, которые отображаются пользователю в зависимости от того, с чем он сейчас работает. Команды управления вынесены на главное окно (так как есть повторяющиеся команды). Нужно скрыть команды, которые не относятся (не могут быть применены) к текущему контейнеру контента. На текущий момент я реализовал это через словари.

```
Dictionary<string, CommandConfigure> _commandConfig;
```

Класс CommandConfigure пока представляет собой просто структуру с двумя полями (реализуют интерфейс INotifyProprtyChanged): имя и видимость (булево).

В разметке использую прямое обращение по имени (ключ словаря) к нужному элементу конфигурации:

```
<MenuItem Visibility="{Binding CommandConfig[<NameMenuItem>].Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" ... >
```

Вот по этому случаю у меня вопрос: можно ли данное многословие поместить в шаблон, и сделать обращение к элементу словаря не прямым текстом, а, например, привязкой к свойству UID?

Я понимаю, что использование словарей в данном случае не совсем правильно, но пока других решений не придумал. Буду благодарен за подсказки или готовые решения.

Спасибо

Comment: Сделайте конвертер, который будет принимать строку, потом смотреть словарь и возвращать `Visibility`, саму строку положите в `Tag`, а в общем стиле для всех меню напишите `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MenuVisibilityConverter}}"/>`

Comment: А можно привязаться не к Tag, а к UID?

Comment: Можно и к нему, наверное, попробуйте.

Comment: Попробовал, все получилось как надо. Спасибо

Comment: Отлично, оформите ответом, будет полезно.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, при таком подходе (через конвертер), если поменяется одно из значений в словаре - это теперь никак не отразится на свойстве элемента управления? Как мне инициировать перечитывание значений свойств?

Comment: Нет, не отразится, View же об этом не узнает никак. А вот как это сделать — хороший вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP А можно сделать так: <MenuItem Visibility={Binding CommandConfig, ....> А вот дальше как-то передать в конвертер значение Uid? Или использовать MarkupExtension, но надо как-то прибиндиться к свойству CommandConfig